# Getting the rowid after adding an item with CI cart?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

On the codeigniter website it says the the insert() method will return a $rowid of the latest inserted product. However How exactly do I grab it?

```
$data = array();

$insert = $this->cart->insert($data);
```

I tried $insert['rowid'] and $insert->rowid but neither seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: what does var_dump($insert) return?

Comment: `The insert() method will return the $rowid if you successfully insert a single item.` An empty array isn't a single item

Comment: The array is not empty in the actual code, I just didnt want to post unnecessary information.

Comment: Unnecessary != wrong. Anyway, var_dump($insert) as martin suggested, and post some more code

Answer (score 2):

introducing: **insert_id()**

like this

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
return $id;
```

in your model, lets call it friend_model

```
function insertRow()
{
// Prepare data, normally you would pass this in
$data = array(
'first' => 'john',
'last' => 'smith'
);
// insert data
$this->db->insert( 'friends', $data );
// confirm insert       
if ( $this->db->affected_rows() == '1' )
// return new ID
{ $id = $this->db->insert_id();
return $id; }
// else did not insert, return false 
else {return FALSE;}
}
```

in your controller, check if you got an id back from model

```
if(! $id = $this->friend_model->insertRow() )
// it no work
{ // some error method 
}
else
{ // success ! 
}
```